# StaggaredGridLayoutManager not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I am trying to change the view from Grid to list and list to Grid using `Recyclerview`. when i Run my app first i am getting view in grid manner like first image

1. 

[image]

Now when i click on icon to convert view from Grid to list i am getting it list manner like this

2.

[image]

3. but now if i click on icon again to change view it will give proper output

[image]

Now issue is why i am not able to get view in grid manner as mentioned in 1 screenshot

oncreateview

```
 gridimg.setOnClickListener(this);
   llm = new LinearLayoutManager(ProductListActivity.this);
         rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewproduts);

        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Getting Json response using volley and setting adapter

```
 private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {



        showpDialog();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest( url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("ress", response.toString());
                        productlist = new ArrayList<ProductListModel>();
                        // Parsing json

                        ch_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        color_list=new ArrayList<String>();

                        try {....................

                                   rvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ProductListActivity.this,productlist,ch_list);
                            rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        hidepDialog();

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("ErrorVolley", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();

            }
        });


        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(req, "jreq");
    }
```

onclick

```
 case R.id.product_grid:

                Toast.makeText(ProductListActivity.this, "Refresh App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isViewWithCatalog = !isViewWithCatalog;
               supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                //loading = false;
                rv.setLayoutManager(isViewWithCatalog ? new LinearLayoutManager(this) : new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
                break;
```

Comment: which layoutManager you are setting at the time of start means initialize time?

Comment: linearlayoutmanager as mentioned in question

Comment: at the time of initialize, you are setting linearLayoutManager not StaggeredGridLayoutManager... because of this you are not getting proper output 1st time.

Comment: Post the code where you initialize RecyclerView and set the adapter.

Comment: @MonishKamble please read question again its there already

Comment: @Mehta then what is the solution for that

Comment: try to set StaggeredGridLayoutManager at the time of initialize.

Comment: @Mehta nope same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
gridimg.setOnClickListener(this);
   llm = new LinearLayoutManager(ProductListActivity.this);
         rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewproduts);

        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

to

```
gridimg.setOnClickListener(this);
   llm =  new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
         rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewproduts);

    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Comment: thanks it worked it was such a silly mistake..saved my day

Comment: Right now at first it shows gridview , what if i want to show it in listview manner.. can you tell??